# Как сделать выборку товаров, имеющих все комбинации характеристик?

Tags: python, django, orm

Упрощенный вариант модели:

```py
class Product():
    name = CharField()
    width = IntegerField()
    height = IntegerField() 
    diameter = IntegerField()
```

Пользователь вводит 2 сета размеров, допустим:

```py
w = 10
h = 20
d = 30

w2 = 15
h2 = 25
d2 = 35
```

Моя задача выбрать все товары первого и второго размера, только если и первый и второй размер присутствуют в базе одновременно.

Например, вот такая пара товаров должна попасть в выборку:

```
<'Модель1', 10, 20, 30>
<'Модель1', 15, 15, 35>
```

А вот такой товар в выборку попасть не должен, т.к. у него нет пары со вторым размером:

```
<'Модель2', 10, 20, 30>
```

Можно ли сделать такую выборку одним запросом и как? Или придется решать задачу, храня какие-то промежуточные результаты?

Comment: Как у вас сейчас это работает? Для каждого размера делаете запрос к базе и потом обрабатываете эти результаты?

Comment: @Andrey ну я делаю выборку первого и второго варианта через `or`. То есть выбираются все варианты, где есть хотя бы один из размеров. Получившуюся выборку перебираю питоньим циклом и формирую список с проверкой, что присутствую  оба размера. Так себе решение, но лучше пока не нашел.

Comment: Запостил свое решение, может быть как-то поможет вам.

Answer (score 2):

**Начал изучать django, решал эту задачу 3 дня. Пока решал, узнал много нового, так что спасибо огромное за вопрос!**

Начал новый проект `market` и приложение `goods`.

***Вот дерево:***
[image]

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Good(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    height = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    diameter = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***Через Админку создал 6 моделей товаров:***

```
name = Shoes, height = 10, width = 20, diameter = 30
name = Shoes, height = 15, width = 15, diameter = 35
name = Shoes, height = 20, width = 40, diameter = 50 
name = Sneakers, height = 10, width = 20, diameter = 30 
name = Sneakers, height = 15, width = 15, diameter = 35 
name = Slippers, height = 10, width = 20, diameter = 30
```

***forms.py***

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from goods.models import Good

class DoubleCheckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Good
        exclude = ['name'] # Exclude name
```

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from goods.models import Good
from . import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create your views here.


def search(request):
    first_form = forms.DoubleCheckForm(prefix="first_form")
    second_form = forms.DoubleCheckForm(prefix="second_form")
    context = {'first_form':first_form,
                'second_form':second_form,
                'result':None}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_form = forms.DoubleCheckForm(request.POST, prefix="first_form")
        second_form = forms.DoubleCheckForm(request.POST, prefix="second_form")

        if first_form.is_valid() and second_form.is_valid():
            print('VALIDATION SUCCESS!')
            first_user_height = first_form.cleaned_data.get('height')
            first_user_width = first_form.cleaned_data.get('width')
            first_user_diameter = first_form.cleaned_data.get('diameter')

            second_user_height = second_form.cleaned_data.get('height')
            second_user_width = second_form.cleaned_data.get('width')
            second_user_diameter = second_form.cleaned_data.get('diameter')

            #QuerySet of corresponding to first_form's parameters goods
            g1 = Good.objects.all().filter(height = first_user_height, width = first_user_width, diameter = first_user_diameter) 
            #QuerySet of corresponding to second_form's parameters goods
            g2 = Good.objects.all().filter(height = second_user_height, width = second_user_width, diameter = second_user_diameter)

            l1 = [i.name for i in g1] #List that consists from good's name from first QuerySet
            l2 = [c.name for c in g2] #List that consists from good's name from second QuerySet

            cur_res = [name for name in l1 if name in l2] #Good's names that correspon both to first and second form's parameters
            result = ''
            for i in cur_res:
                result += f'{i}, '
            context['result'] = result[0:-2]

    return render(request, 'goods/search.html', context)
```

***ШАБЛОН search.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    h3{
      font-size: 38px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(128, 128, 128), #3cdede); /*#eee, #333*/
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
  </style>  

  <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(128, 128, 128), #3cdede)">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
            <p class="lead">You can type two kind of parametres to look for goods that relate to this parametres and have the same name</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-5">
                        {{first_form.as_ul}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-5">
                        {{second_form.as_ul}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-9">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit" style="height: 2.4em; width: 7em">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br>
            <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-9">
                    {% if result %}
                        <h3><em>Result: {{result}}</em></h3>                

                    {% endif %}   
                </div>  
            </div>      


        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Теперь вводим данные в форму:**
[image]

**Нажимаем на кнопку и получаем результат!**
[image: voila]

***P.S***
**Надеюсь Я ответил на ваш вопрос =))**

***P.P.S***
2 вопроса, которые я не смог нагуглить и задал так же на stackOverflow :D
[Первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086814/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8/1086900#1086900)
[Второй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087136/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/1087212#1087212)

***P.P.P.S***
**Как говорится: *Feel free to post any questions in the comments below* :D**

***P.P.P.P.S* 
Слишко много ПэЭсов.. Так вообще можно *:D***

Comment: Воу-воу, спасило, я пока ничего не понял, но я изучу ваш ответ)

Comment: А, я понял. Вы просто делаете 2 запроса а потом в самом питоне уже обрабатываете результаты. Проблема такого подхода в низкой произодительности на больших выборках. Я хотел сделать это одним запросом к sql, чтобы запрос был быстрый)

Comment: Как есть, думаю есть другой вариант, но я его не нашёл

Answer (score 0):

снова я. Думаю тот скрипт, который я написал в прошлом ответе очень даже работоспособный и быстрый.

я немного обновил модель: добавил ещё одно поле, которое хранит количество товара, ведь это реалистично/

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Good(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    height = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    diameter = models.IntegerField()
    number = models.IntegerField() # NEW

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

а в ***forms.py*** в `exclude` добавил `number`, чтоб этого поля в выводе не было

Создал незамысловатый скрипт фэйкер, который наполняет бд, чтоб не делать это в ручную
***populate_goods.py***

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'market.settings')

import django
django.setup()

## FAKE POP SCRIPT
import random
from goods.models import Good
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()

fake_name_list = ['Apres-ski', 'Waders', 'Combat boots', 'Trekking boots', 'Brogues',
                  'Bast shoes', 'kamik', 'Boots', 'Clog', 'Crackowes',
                  'Bedroom', 'Monquis', 'Moccasins', 'Slip-ons shoes', 'Athletic shoe',
                  'Cowboy boots', 'Keds', 'Derby', 'Gibson', 'Bucks',
                  'Geta', 'Galoshes', 'Flip-flops', 'jandals', 'Japanese sandals']
fake_height_list = [10, 15, 20, 30, 35, 40]
fake_width_list = [10, 15, 20, 30, 35, 40]
fake_diameter_list = [10, 15, 20, 30, 35, 40]


def populate(N = 5):
    global number_of_created_models
    number_of_created_models = N

    for entry in range(N):

        # Create the fake data for that entry
        fake_name = random.choice(fake_name_list)
        fake_height = random.choice(fake_height_list)
        fake_width = random.choice(fake_width_list)
        fake_diameter = random.choice(fake_diameter_list)
        fake_number = random.randint(1, 99)

        # Create the new good entry

        fake_good = Good.objects.get_or_create(name = fake_name,
                                                height = fake_height,
                                                width = fake_width,
                                                diameter = fake_diameter,
                                                number = fake_number)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Populating script!')
    populate(100)
    print('Populating completed!')
    print('Создано {} Моделей'.format(number_of_created_models))
```

Далее во ***views.py*** если форма валидная импортирую time, чтобы засечь, сколько выполняется скрипт. И одну строчку, которая вычисляет сколько элементов в модели.

```
def search(request):
    first_form = forms.DoubleCheckForm(prefix="first_form")
    second_form = forms.DoubleCheckForm(prefix="second_form")
    context = {'first_form':first_form,
                'second_form':second_form,
                'result':None}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_form = forms.DoubleCheckForm(request.POST, prefix="first_form")
        second_form = forms.DoubleCheckForm(request.POST, prefix="second_form")

        if first_form.is_valid() and second_form.is_valid():

            import time
            start_time = time.time()

            print('VALIDATION SUCCESS!')
            first_user_height = first_form.cleaned_data.get('height')
            first_user_width = first_form.cleaned_data.get('width')
            first_user_diameter = first_form.cleaned_data.get('diameter')

            second_user_height = second_form.cleaned_data.get('height')
            second_user_width = second_form.cleaned_data.get('width')
            second_user_diameter = second_form.cleaned_data.get('diameter')

            #QuerySet of corresponding to first_form's parameters goods
            g1 = Good.objects.all().filter(height = first_user_height, width = first_user_width, diameter = first_user_diameter) 
            #QuerySet of corresponding to second_form's parameters goods
            g2 = Good.objects.all().filter(height = second_user_height, width = second_user_width, diameter = second_user_diameter)

            l1 = [i.name for i in g1] #List that consists from good's name from first QuerySet
            l2 = [c.name for c in g2] #List that consists from good's name from second QuerySet

            cur_res = [name for name in l1 if name in l2] #Good's names that correspon both to first and second form's parameters
            result = ''
            for i in cur_res:
                result += f'{i}, '
            context['result'] = result[0:-2]

            execution_time = time.time() - start_time
            context['execution_time'] = execution_time

            context['number_of_models'] = len(Good.objects.all())

    return render(request, 'goods/search.html', context)
```

А в шаблоне добавил 2 template teg'а, чтобы вывести, сколько времени заняло вычисление, и сколько элементов в модели.
***search.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    h3{
      font-size: 38px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(128, 128, 128), #3cdede); /*#eee, #333*/
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
    h4{
      font-size: 28px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;         
    }
  </style>  

  <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(128, 128, 128), #3cdede)">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
            <p class="lead">You can type two kind of parametres to look for goods that relate to this parametres and have the same name</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-5">
                        {{first_form.as_ul}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-5">
                        {{second_form.as_ul}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-9">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit" style="height: 2.4em; width: 7em">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br>
            <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-9">
                    {% if result %}
                        <h3><em>Result: {{result}}</em></h3>
                        <h4>Execution takes {{execution_time}} seconds</h4>
                        <h4>we have {{number_of_models}} Different Goods in the storage</h4>                

                    {% endif %}   
                </div>  
            </div>      


        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

С 200, 500, 1000, 2000 элементов вычисление выполнялось от **Пяти тысячных секунд до Пятнадцати сотых секунд**
[image]

[image]

***Далее решил затестить с 10000 элементов модели***
Самое медленное **это 23 Тысячных секунды**
[image]

За пять дней регулярной работы над эти вопросом не нашёл как это можно сделать просто запросом без какой-либо обработки. To my mind это логично ведь ситуация нестандартная(используется не так часто), я думаю от 0,005 до 0,02 секунды, это очень быстро, а в обычном магазине будет максимум 100-150 различных товаров (по моему мнению) и это будет выполнятся ещё быстрей. 10000 товаров может быть только в таких магазинах как AliExpress, и всё равно всё выполняется очень быстро. **Так вот** хочу у вас спросить 0,005 или 0,02 секунды это много?

Я продолжаю изучать Веб-разработку, python, django, если найду какое-нибудь Омега-Интересное решение напишу. =)

Answer (score 0):

Модель:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    width = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    diameter = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.width}x{self.height}x{self.diameter}'
```

Пример данных в бд и список размеров, по которым будем искать:

```
In [61]: Product.objects.all()                                                                                                                        
Out[61]: <QuerySet [<Product: Product_1 - 10x20x30>, <Product: Product_1 - 15x25x35>, <Product: Product_2 - 15x25x35>, <Product: Product_3 - 15x25x35>, <Product: Product_3 - 10x20x30>, <Product: Product_4 - 1x1x1>]>

In [62]: sizes                                                                                                                                        
Out[62]: ['10x20x30', '15x25x35']
```

Инструменты, чтобы отслеживать количество запросов к бд:

```
In [63]: from django.db import connection, reset_queries

In [64]: reset_queries()

In [65]: connection.queries
Out[65]: []
```

Параметры продукта находятся в разных полях модели, поэтому сгенерируем новое поле с размером продукта.
Для этого используем `annotate()` и функцию [`Concat()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat). И сразу отсекаем объекты, у которых значение `product_size` не в списке `sizes`:

```
In [66]: from django.db.models import CharField, Count, Value

In [67]: from django.db.models.functions import Concat

In [68]: products = Product.objects.annotate( 
    ...:    product_size=Concat('width', Value('x'), 'height', Value('x'), 'diameter', 
    ...:                        output_field=CharField() 
    ...:    ) 
    ...: ).filter(product_size__in=sizes)
```

Теперь посчитаем сколько раз встречается каждое имя в `products` и оставим только те имена, количество которых равно длине списка `sizes`:

```
In [69]: names = [ 
    ...:     p['name']  
    ...:     for p in products.values('name').annotate(count=Count('name'))  
    ...:     if p['count'] == len(sizes) 
    ...: ]                                                                                                                                            

In [70]: names                                                                                                                                        
Out[70]: ['Product_1', 'Product_3']
```

И оставляем только те продукты имена которых есть в списке `names`:

```
In [71]: products.filter(name__in=names)                                                                                                              
Out[71]: <QuerySet [<Product: Product_1 - 10x20x30>, <Product: Product_1 - 15x25x35>, <Product: Product_3 - 15x25x35>, <Product: Product_3 - 10x20x30>]>
```

Смотрим сколько сделано запросов к бд:

```
In [72]: connection.queries                                                                                                                           
Out[72]: 
[{'sql': 'SELECT "products_product"."name", COUNT("products_product"."name") AS "count" FROM "products_product" WHERE COALESCE("products_product"."width", \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE(\'x\', \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE("products_product"."height", \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE(\'x\', \'\') || COALESCE("products_product"."diameter", \'\'), \'\'), \'\'), \'\') IN (\'10x20x30\', \'15x25x35\') GROUP BY "products_product"."name"',
  'time': '0.000'},
 {'sql': 'SELECT "products_product"."id", "products_product"."name", "products_product"."width", "products_product"."height", "products_product"."diameter", COALESCE("products_product"."width", \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE(\'x\', \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE("products_product"."height", \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE(\'x\', \'\') || COALESCE("products_product"."diameter", \'\'), \'\'), \'\'), \'\') AS "product_size" FROM "products_product" WHERE (COALESCE("products_product"."width", \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE(\'x\', \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE("products_product"."height", \'\') || COALESCE(COALESCE(\'x\', \'\') || COALESCE("products_product"."diameter", \'\'), \'\'), \'\'), \'\') IN (\'10x20x30\', \'15x25x35\') AND "products_product"."name" IN (\'Product_1\', \'Product_3\')) LIMIT 21',
  'time': '0.000'}]

In [73]: len(connection.queries)                                                         
Out[73]: 2
```

Я не нашел способа избавиться от `names = [p['name'] for p in ...]`. 
Если придумаете как сделать все одним запросом в ORM, напишите комментарий к моему ответу, любопытно узнать есть ли решение.

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле то, что я делю довольно похоже на ваше решение)