# Как дублировать форму но оставить для неё одну кнопку и красивый вывод

Tags: html, python, css, django, form

Есть модель придуманного товара. хочу сделать поиск товара по двум разным размерам (длина и ширина), но выводить только если товар с таким названием есть в обоих размерах.

Так вот форму сделал некрасивую, как сделать , чтобы вывод был примерно таким(Рисовал в paint=) )[image]

А то у меня всё идёт как `<p>` 
И в приоритете, чтоб форма была именно `models.Form`, но если знаете как сделать такой вывод с `forms.Form` Обязательно пишите. ***Кнопка одна должна быть***

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Good(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    height = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    diameter = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***forms.py***

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from goods.models import Good

def check_for_positive(value):
    if value <= 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('NEEDS TO BE GREATER THEAN 0!')

#class DoubleCheck(forms.ModelForm):
    # Form Fields go here
#   class Meta:
#       model = Good
#       exclude = ['name'] # Exclude name


class DoubleCheck(forms.Form):

    height1 = forms.IntegerField(validators = [check_for_positive])
    width1 = forms.IntegerField(validators = [check_for_positive])
    diameter1 = forms.IntegerField(validators = [check_for_positive])
    height2 = forms.IntegerField(validators = [check_for_positive])
    width2 = forms.IntegerField(validators = [check_for_positive])
    diameter2 = forms.IntegerField(validators = [check_for_positive])
    botcather = forms.CharField(required = False, widget = forms.HiddenInput, validators = [validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])
```

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from goods.models import Good
from . import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create your views here.

def storage(request):
    goods_list = Good.objects.order_by('name')
    goods_dict = {'goods_list':goods_list}
    return render(request, 'goods/storage.html', context = goods_dict)

def search(request):
    form = forms.DoubleCheck
    form_dict = {'form':form,
                'result':False}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.DoubleCheck(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print('VALIDATION SUCCESS!')
            height_user1 = form.cleaned_data.get('height1')
            width_user1 = form.cleaned_data.get('width1')
            diameter_user1 = form.cleaned_data.get('diameter1')

            height_user2 = form.cleaned_data.get('height2')
            width_user2 = form.cleaned_data.get('width2')
            diameter_user2 = form.cleaned_data.get('diameter2')

            g1 = Good.objects.all().filter(height = height_user1, width = width_user1, diameter = diameter_user1)
            g2 = Good.objects.all().filter(height = height_user2, width = width_user2, diameter = diameter_user2)

            l1 = [i.name for i in g1]
            l2 = [c.name for c in g2]

            result = [name for name in l1 if name in l2]
            form_dict['result'] = result

    return render(request, 'goods/search.html', context = form_dict)

def registerPage(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('========SUCCESS========')
            form.save()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'goods/register.html', context)

def loginPage(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'goods/login.html', context)
```

***search.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
            <p class="lead">You can type two kind of parametres to look for goods that relate to this parametres and have the same name</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
            <form method="POST">
                {{form.as_ul}}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </form>

            {% if result %}
                <h3><em>Result: {{result}}</em></h3>                

            {% endif %}             


        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верным решением в данном случае есть использование [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) и [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms)

**forms**

```
class DoubleCheckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Good
        exclude = ['name']
```

**views**

```
first_form = DoubleCheckForm(prefix="first_form")
second_form = DoubleCheckForm(prefix="second_form")
form_dict = {'first_form': first_form, 'second_form': second_form}
```

**template**

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ first_form.as_ul }}
  {{ second_form.as_ul }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```